# How to get everyone's calendar/meeting information from outlook server？

Tags: outlook, calendar, meeting-request

I'm developing an outlook application that displays meeting information of all users (obtained from the user's calendar), but I only found the api to obtain the calendar information of a single user, and did not find the api to obtain the meeting information of everyone.

Can this be achieved? What is the api?

Comment: Aren't meetings stored as calendar events?

Comment: The meeting is stored as a calendar event, which is a personal behavior. If I obtain everyone’s meeting information by obtaining a personal calendar, then I need to install a software on each personal computer. Is there an api that can get everyone's information at once with the outlook server。